# overlay over fragment and disable fragment functionality

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that fits half the screen which I want to put an overlay over and I want the fragments functionality (scrolling and clicking on items in it) to be disabled.  I also want the activity to register a click anywhere on the disabled fragment (which will remove the overlay and re enable the fragment)

My first idea was to try find a way to pause the fragment, but nothing really worked, so now I am thinking about putting another fragment or possibly dialogue over the fragment and so that it covers the scrollbar and clicks in the fragment and registers its own clicks.  Would this be possible?  Would it be better to do it with a fragment or dialogue?

Comment: did you try to put a view over the fragment layout with a click listener?

Comment: wow that seems like a much simpler solution, let me try it and get back to you.

Comment: the overlay looks great, but it hasnt disabled the functionality of the fragment underneath, i can still scroll and click on objects inside the fragment

Comment: also the overlay onclicklistener isnt working, i must be doing something wrong

Comment: okay i changed the view to a butonn and it works perfectly